# designing my own simple chapter style

Tags: chapters

I want to design a simple chapter title like the following figure. I want to use `xepersian` package and `reportclass` and I tested some other chapter style designs but it didn't work with `xepersian` package so I just being satisfied with this simple one.

the following code results in the usual style.

```
‎\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{report}‎‎‎
‎\usepackage{xepersian}‎‎
‎\settextfont[Scale=1.5]{B Nazanin}‎‎
‎
‎\begin{document}
‎\chapter{‏شروع کار}‎
\end{document}‎
```

I want something a little different for example much more lower from the top of the page and with a line beneath it.

[image]

How can I do this?

(In the above figure, `فصل اول` means `chapter one` and `شروع کار` is just a title)

Comment: While you specified the documentclass and xepersian, you also need to specify a font.  A minimum working example would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I copied and modified `\@makechapterhead` from `report-xetex-bidi`.  Without the `xepersian` package it gives an error for `\if@RTL` not defined.  With `xepersian` it can't find the font (probably due to my setup).  Other than that, it looks okay.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.5]{B Nazanin}‎‎

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \if@RTL\raggedleft\else\raggedright\fi \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \Large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \normalsize\rule{0.5\textwidth}{1pt}
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
‎\chapter{‏شروع کار}‎
\end{document}
```

Comment: How I can increase the space between chapter title and chapter number?

Comment: Restore and adjust the \vskip I commented out.